# SQL: Grouped average-if / case SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, sql, select, average

I have a database that looks like this SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa02e/1

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`Store` varchar(1), `Date` date, `Product` varchar(2), `Weekday` int, `Month` int, `Revenue` float)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`Store`, `Date`, `Product`, `Weekday`, `Month`, `Revenue`)
VALUES
    ('a', '20160101', 'aa', 5, 1, 1.5),
    ('a', '20160101', 'bb', 5, 1, 4),
    ('a', '20160101', 'cc', 5, 1, 3.5),
    ('a', '20160108', 'dd', 5, 1, 2.5),
    ('a', '20160108', 'ee', 5, 1, 5),
    ('b', '20160204', 'aa', 4, 2, 9.5),
    ('b', '20160204', 'bb', 4, 2, 4),
    ('b', '20160204', 'cc', 4, 2, 3),
    ('b', '20160211', 'dd', 4, 2, 1.5),
    ('b', '20160211', 'ee', 4, 2, 2.5)
;

 SELECT * FROM table1;
+-------+------------+---------+---------+-------+---------+
| Store | Date       | Product | Weekday | Month | Revenue |
+-------+------------+---------+---------+-------+---------+
| a     | 2016-01-01 | aa      |       5 |     1 |     1.5 |
| a     | 2016-01-01 | bb      |       5 |     1 |       4 |
| a     | 2016-01-01 | cc      |       5 |     1 |     3.5 |
| a     | 2016-01-08 | dd      |       5 |     1 |     2.5 |
| a     | 2016-01-08 | ee      |       5 |     1 |       5 |
| b     | 2016-02-04 | aa      |       4 |     2 |     9.5 |
| b     | 2016-02-04 | bb      |       4 |     2 |       4 |
| b     | 2016-02-04 | cc      |       4 |     2 |       3 |
| b     | 2016-02-11 | dd      |       4 |     2 |     1.5 |
| b     | 2016-02-11 | ee      |       4 |     2 |     2.5 |
+-------+------------+---------+---------+-------+---------+
```

It shows revenue data for stores incl. products, date and the respective day/month.
I want to select the following:

- Store
- Monthly revenue totals (i.e. what is the total revenue for store a in Jan?)
- Weekday revenue averages (i.e. what is the avg revenue for store a on Thu?)

The first and second bullet are straightforward, but I'm having problems with the last one.
Currently, it takes the average over all products and all dates (assuming the weekday matches). What I need are the following steps:

- Sum up all revenues for a store and a particular date (e.g. for store b: 9.5+4+3=16.5 for Feb 4th, and 1.5+2.5=4 for Feb 11th) if that date has the same weekday (here Thursday)
- Take the average of the two values (e.g. avg(16.5,4)=10.25)

How can I accomplish that?
Thank you

Here is the query:

```
SELECT
  Store,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Month = 1 THEN Revenue ELSE NULL END) AS REVENUE_JAN,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Month = 2 THEN Revenue ELSE NULL END) AS REVENUE_FEB,
  AVG(CASE WHEN Weekday = 4 THEN Revenue ELSE NULL END) AS REVENUE_THU,
  AVG(CASE WHEN Weekday = 5 THEN Revenue ELSE NULL END) AS REVENUE_FRI
FROM Table1
GROUP BY
  Store
;
```

Comment: Please add all relevant info directly into your question. Links break, especially SQLFiddle

Comment: I don't understand what the month and weekday columns do. Also, I suspect you meant DECIMAL instead of FLOAT

Comment: Month is the integer for the month (i.e. 1 = January), weekday is the integer for the day (i.e. 1 = Monday)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The weekday average is tricky.  Your query is getting the average "order size" per weekday.  But you want the total revenue.

One method is to first aggregate by weekday, but that is a bit of a mess.  Instead, you can use this trick of calculating the average by dividing the total revenue by the number of days:

```
SELECT Store,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Month = 1 THEN Revenue ELSE NULL END) AS REVENUE_JAN,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Month = 2 THEN Revenue ELSE NULL END) AS REVENUE_FEB,
       (SUM(CASE WHEN Weekday = 4 THEN Revenue END) /
        COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Weekday = 4 THEN Date END)
       ) AS REVENUE_THU,
       (SUM(CASE WHEN Weekday = 5 THEN Revenue END) /
        COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Weekday = 5 THEN Date END)
       ) AS REVENUE_FRI
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Store;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  t1.store,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Month = 1 THEN Revenue ELSE NULL END) AS REVENUE_JAN,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Month = 2 THEN Revenue ELSE NULL END) AS REVENUE_FEB,
  daily.REVENUE_THU,
  daily.REVENUE_FRI
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN (
  SELECT
    Store,
    weekday,
    avg(CASE WHEN weekday = 4 THEN sum_rev END) as REVENUE_THU,
    avg(CASE WHEN weekday = 5 THEN sum_rev END) as REVENUE_FRI
  FROM (
    SELECT
      Store, date, weekday,
      SUM(revenue) AS sum_rev
    FROM Table1
    GROUP BY
      Store, date, weekday
  ) AS foo
  GROUP BY Store, weekday
) AS daily ON daily.store = t1.store
GROUP BY
  t1.store
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this solution it return average for chosen day of chosen store

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sumForDayStore(IN vday INTEGER, IN vStore VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
    DECLARE totalDays INTEGER;
    DECLARE totalRevenu INTEGER;

    SET totalDays = (SELECT count(*) FROM Table1 WHERE WeekDay = vDay AND store = vStore);
    SET totalRevenu = (SELECT sum(Revenue) FROM Table1 WHERE WeekDay = vDay AND store = vStore);

    SELECT totalRevenu/totalDays;
END;
```

CALL sumForDayStore(5,'a');

Answer (score 0):

How about this one:

```
SELECT mnth.Store, REVENUE_JAN, REVENUE_FEB, avg(rthu) REVENUE_THU, avg(rfri) REVENUE_FRI
FROM 
(Select Store, sum(case when Month = 1 then Revenue else NULL END) REVENUE_JAN, 
sum(case when Month = 2 then Revenue else NULL END) REVENUE_FEB 
From Table1 group by Store) as mnth 

join 

(Select Store, sum(case when Weekday = 4 then Revenue end) rThu,
sum(case when Weekday = 5 then Revenue end) rFri from Table1 group by Store, Date) as dys 

on mnth.Store = dys.Store

group by mnth.Store, REVENUE_JAN, REVENUE_FEB
```

I compared the performance of this with the query in the first answer and it shows better performance according to SQL server execution plan (1.6 times faster). Maybe this would be helpful on a larger data set.